# Why Is This UseEffect Keep on Running on Every Render Even When Dependency Is Filled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to sort the table by name when I click name header but as soon as I remove that "[]" dependency in useEffect, getData() within useEffect runs every second. So I filled the dependency array with users state so my expectation was whenever users state gets updated then useEffect will run. But it still runs every second. I don't know why this is happening. Should I be using useMemo somewhere?
https://codesandbox.io/s/clement-awad-intermediate-react-interview-practice-jmeh4?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20

export default function App() {
  let [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const flattenObj = (obj) => {
    let result = {};
    for (const i in obj) {
      if (typeof obj[i] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[i])) {
        const temp = flattenObj(obj[i]);
        for (const j in temp) {
          result[i + "_" + j] = temp[j];
        }
      } else {
        result[i] = obj[i];
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [users]);

  async function getData() {
    try {
      let result = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20");
      let resultData = result.data.results.map((data) => flattenObj(data));
      console.log(resultData);
      setUsers(resultData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  const sortByName = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
    let sorted = users.sort((a, b) => a.name_first.localeCompare(b.name_first));
    setUsers(sorted);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="column" onClick={sortByName}>
              Name
            </th>
            <th scope="column">Location Street Number</th>
            <th scope="column">Location City</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {users.map((value, idx) => {
          return (
            <>
              <tbody key={idx}>
                <tr>
                  <td>{value.name_first}</td>
                  <td>{value.location_street_number}</td>
                  <td>{value.location_city}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Since `users` is a dependency for the effect, the effect gets called when `users` changes identity.
2. The effect calls `getData()`.
3. The `getData()` function calls `setUsers` with a brand new object `resultData`, which means `users` changes identity on next update.
4. See step 1.

Since `getData()` uses no state or props, you'll just want `[]` for the dependency array for the effect, so `getData()` gets called exactly once.

Comment: That make sense. Currently, when I click name header in the table, SortByName() function runs which updates users state so I was expecting to see sorted name on the table. But getData() function runs too which is over-riding my result from SortByName(). Ok, I think I need to create another useEffect for sortedName. More work to do. Thanks!

Comment: Either that, or use `useMemo` to derive the sorted (or not sorted) values from `users` and a `sortByName` state atom.